Failed TCP Socket Communication
I tried to communicate with my friend on terminal using TCP socket. But i failed.I think i can connect server but it cannot be. i gave ip address and port info when i run program, then i waited long time for entering message and i entered. After that there was nothing on server side.
server.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 if (argc != 3){
 cout << "Usage: ./server <CLIENT_IP_ADDRESS> <PORT>\n"; 
 return -1;
 }

char* client_ip_address = argv[1];
int port = stoi(argv[2]);

// Create a socket for server
int serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (serverSocket == -1) { // If the socket creation is unsuccessful, it returns -1
    cout << "Socket creation has failed.\n";
    return -1;
}

// Address and Port informations
sockaddr_in serverAddress; //sockaddr_in: It is the data type that is used to store the address of the socket.
serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; 
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(port); //This function is used to convert the unsigned int from machine byte order to network byte order.
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(client_ip_address);


// Socket binding
bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)); 
   

if (listen(serverSocket, 10) == -1) {
    cout << "Connection listening error: " <<endl;
    close(serverSocket);
    return -1;
}

std::cout << "The server has been started. Listening for connections...\n";

sockaddr_in clientAddr;
socklen_t clientSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &clientSize);

while (true) {
    
    char messageBuffer[1024] = {0};
    recv(clientSocket, messageBuffer, sizeof(messageBuffer), 0);
    cout << "Message from client: " << messageBuffer << endl;

    if (strcmp(messageBuffer, "Fin") == 0) {
        close(serverSocket);
        break;
    }
    // Sending a message to the client.
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    cout << "Enter a message: ";
    cin.getline(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "Fin") == 0) {
        close(serverSocket);
        break;
    }
}

std::cout << "(Fin) message received. Server is shutting down...\n";

return 0;
}

client.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 if (argc != 3){
 cout << "Usage: ./client <SERVER_IP_ADRES> <PORT>\n"; 
 return -1;
 }


char* server_ip_address = argv[1];
int port = stoi(argv[2]);

// Create a socket for client
int clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (clientSocket == -1) {
    cout << "Socket creation has failed.\n";
    return -1;
}

// Address and Port informations
sockaddr_in server_address;
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_port = htons(port);
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip_address);


// Connecting server
  connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));

while (true) {
    // Kullanıcıdan bir mesaj al
    char messageBuffer[1024] = {0};
    std::cout << "Enter a message: ";
    cin.getline(messageBuffer, sizeof(messageBuffer));
    // Sending a message to the server.
    send(clientSocket, messageBuffer, strlen(messageBuffer), 0);
    if (string(messageBuffer)== "Fin"){
        close(clientSocket);
        break;
    }
    
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    ssize_t bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    cout << "Message from server: " << string(buffer, bytesReceived) << std::endl;
    if (string(buffer)== "Fin"){
        close(clientSocket);
        break;
    }

    }
    std::cout << "(Fin) message received. Client is shutting down...\n";


return 0;
}

I took turns waiting to communicate with my friend. I achieved this in my own local. I opened a new tab in my terminal and ran and tested both the server and the client from there, it worked without any problems. I can't do this with my friend from another city.

port forwarded right?

What IP address(es) are you using?

dont give out ip addresses

i assigned random port info. of course i checked same port value
./server 192.168.x.x 23456 like that

With no error checking on bind(), accept(), connect(), recv(), send() etc. you have no hope of debugging this problem. Don’t write code like this.

your friend has to use public ip not nat ip 192 and 10 ip addresses are not routed on the internet, they are only for your lan

@user207421 the code is fine, it's a network problem.

@xaxxon It may indeed be a network problem but the code is most certainly not fine.

@user207421 code on SO is supposed to be MINIMAL.   It is fine to have sample code pasted that is not your full code.  You specifically said we could not debug THIS problem with the code as is.   Yes, we can.

@xaxxon you might be right, i am gonna try it sir.  How can i reach nat ip? sorry about my inexperience

see answer below. The only important points in the answer are the first two bullet points as well as the null termination comment.   Everything else is good practice, but not necessary to solve your problem right now.

@xaxxon If the OP had written his code properly we would be telling him why he got ‘conn3tionntefused’,  ‘connect timeout’, ‘network unreachable’, ‘no route to host’, or whatever it is, instead of having to dig out of him error messages that he should have posted in the first place, and instead of  guessing. Furthermore it is all too apparent that this is the real code, not some minimal mock-up, and it would not pass a code review in any shop I haven née in or run since 1976. And I didn’t say we couldn’t debug it. I said he couldn’t. Don’t misquote me thanks.

Since your friend is in another city, they are likely on a different network (unless you setup a private VPN between your two computers).
When communicating with computers on different networks, there are additional steps you need to do outside of your code:

You need to make sure the ISP (Internet Service Provider) on the server side is not blocking incoming connections.  Many ISPs do not allow customers to run servers on their networks unless they pay extra for that feature.

You need to make sure any firewall running on the server computer, or on either network, is not blocking the connection.

If the server computer is running behind a NAT router (which is typical for modern Wifi setups), the router must have a port forwarding rule configured in order to route incoming connections on the WAN side to the server computer on the LAN side. Clients can then connect to the router's public WAN IP/port and be routed to the LAN IP/port that the server socket is listening on.
If the router supports uPNP, you can configure the port forwarding rule dynamically from your server code. Otherwise, you have to configure the router directly.



As for your code itself, there are several problems with it.
In the server:

Make sure to bind() your server socket to the local IP of the network interface that is connected to the router/Internet. Or, you can alternatively bind() the socket to INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) to bind to all network interfaces on the local machine. DO NOT bind to the client's IP, as your code suggests.

You are not doing any error checking on bind(), accept(), recv(), send(), or cin.getline().

recv() does not return a null-terminated string, and you are not terminating your messageBuffer manually. Your client is using the return value of recv() to know how many bytes were actually received. The server needs to do the same thing.

When calling send(), you are not sending any kind of message length or message terminator to let the client know when the message is finished being sent.  For TCP, there is no 1:1 relationship between send() and recv(), both functions can report fewer bytes than requested, so you must call both functions in loops to make sure all expected data is sent/received.


In the client:

You are not doing any error checking on connect(), recv(), send(), or cin.getline().

When calling send() and recv(), you are not handling message termination correctly, same as with the server.


Try something more like this:
server.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string> 
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;
    
bool readRaw(int sckt, void* buffer, size_t bufsize) {
    char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer);
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        ssize_t numBytes = recv(sckt, ptr, bufsize, 0);
        if (numBytes < 0) {
            cout << "Read error: " << errno << '\n';
            return false;
        }
        if (numBytes == 0) {
            cout << "Client disconnected\n";
            return false;
        }
        ptr += numBytes;
        bufsize -= numBytes;
    }
    return true;
}

bool sendRaw(int sckt, const void* buffer, size_t bufsize) {
    const char *ptr = static_cast<const char*>(buffer);
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        ssize_t numBytes = send(sckt, ptr, bufsize, 0);
        if (numBytes < 0) {
            cout << "Send error: " << errno << '\n';
            return false;
        }
        ptr += numBytes;
        bufsize -= numBytes;
    }
    return true;
}

bool readUint32(int sckt, uint32_t &value) {
    if (!readRaw(sckt, &value, sizeof(value))) return false;        
    value = ntohl(value);
    return true;
}

bool sendUint32(int sckt, uint32_t value) {
    value = htonl(value);
    return sendRaw(sckt, &value, sizeof(value)));
}

bool readString(int sckt, string &message) {
    message.clear();
    uint32_t len;
    if (!readUint32(sckt, len)) return false;
    message.resize(len);
    return readRaw(sckt, message.data(), len);
}   

bool sendString(int sckt, const string &message) {
    uint32_t len = message.size();
    if (!sendUint32(len)) return false;
    return sendRaw(sckt, message.c_str(), len);
}

/* alternatively:

bool readString(int sckt, string &message) {
    char buffer[1024], ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    message.clear();
    while (true) {
        if (!readRaw(sckt, &ch, 1)) return false;
        if (ch == '\0') {
            if (len > 0) message.append(buffer, len);
            break;
        }
        if (len == sizeof(buffer)) {
            message.append(buffer, len);
            len = 0;
        }
        buffer[len++] = ch;
    }
    return true;    
}

bool sendString(int sckt, const string &message) {
    return sendRaw(sckt, message.c_str(), message.size()+1);    
}

*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        cout << "Usage: ./server <LISTEN_IP_ADDRESS> <PORT>\n"; 
        return -1;
    }
    
    char* listen_ip_address = argv[1];
    int port = stoi(argv[2]);
    
    int serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSocket < 0) {
        cout << "Socket creation error: " << errno << '\n';
        return -1;
    }
    
    sockaddr_in serverAddress; //sockaddr_in: It is the data type that is used to store the address of the socket.
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(port); //This function is used to convert the unsigned int from machine byte order to network byte order.
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(listen_ip_address);
    
    if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) {
        cout << "Socket bind error: " << errno << '\n';
        close(serverSocket);
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(serverSocket, 1) == -1) {
        cout << "Socket listen error: " << errno << '\n';
        close(serverSocket);
        return -1;
    }
    
    cout << "The server has been started. Listening for connection...\n";
    
    sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    socklen_t clientSize = sizeof(clientAddr);

    int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &clientSize);
    if (clientSocket < 0) {
        cout << "Connection accept error: " << errno << '\n';
        close(serverSocket);
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Client connected\n";

    while (true) {
        
        std::string message;
        if (!readString(clientSocket, message))
            break;

        cout << "Message from client: " << message << '\n'; 

        if (message == "Fin")
            break;

        message.clear();

        cout << "Enter a message: ";
        if (!getline(cin, message))
            break;

        if (!sendString(clientSocket, message))
            break;

        if (message == "Fin")
            break;
    }
    
    cout << "Server is shutting down...\n";
    close(serverSocket);
    
    return 0;
}

client.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string> 
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;
    
bool readRaw(int sckt, void* buffer, size_t bufsize) {
    char *ptr = static_cast<char*>(buffer);
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        ssize_t numBytes = recv(sckt, ptr, bufsize, 0);
        if (numBytes < 0) {
            cout << "Read error: " << errno << '\n';
            return false;
        }
        if (numBytes == 0) {
            cout << "Server disconnected\n";
            return false;
        }
        ptr += numBytes;
        bufsize -= numBytes;
    }
    return true;
}

bool sendRaw(int sckt, const void* buffer, size_t bufsize) {
    const char *ptr = static_cast<const char*>(buffer);
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        ssize_t numBytes = send(sckt, ptr, bufsize, 0);
        if (numBytes < 0) {
            cout << "Send error: " << errno << '\n';
            return false;
        }
        ptr += numBytes;
        bufsize -= numBytes;
    }
    return true;
}

bool readUint32(int sckt, uint32_t &value) {
    if (!readRaw(sckt, &value, sizeof(value))) return false;        
    value = ntohl(value);
    return true;
}

bool sendUint32(int sckt, uint32_t value) {
    value = htonl(value);
    return sendRaw(sckt, &value, sizeof(value)));
}

bool readString(int sckt, string &message) {
    message.clear();
    uint32_t len;
    if (!readUint32(sckt, len)) return false;
    message.resize(len);
    return readRaw(sckt, message.data(), len);
}

bool sendString(int sckt, const string &message) {
    uint32_t len = message.size();
    if (!sendUint32(len)) return false;
    return sendRaw(sckt, message.c_str(), len);
}

/* alternatively:

bool readString(int sckt, string &message) {
    char buffer[1024], ch;
    size_t len = 0;
    message.clear();
    while (true) {
        if (!readRaw(sckt, &ch, 1)) return false;
        if (ch == '\0') {
            if (len > 0) message.append(buffer, len);
            break;
        }
        if (len == sizeof(buffer)) {
            message.append(buffer, len);
            len = 0;
        }
        buffer[len++] = ch;
    }
    return true;    
}

bool sendString(int sckt, const string &message) {
    return sendRaw(sckt, message.c_str(), message.size()+1);    
}

*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc != 3){
        cout << "Usage: ./client <SERVER_IP_ADRES> <PORT>\n"; 
        return -1;
    }

    char* server_ip_address = argv[1];
    int port = stoi(argv[2]);

    int clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (clientSocket < 0) {
        cout << "Socket creation error: " << errno << '\n';
        return -1;
    }
    
    sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip_address);
    
    if (connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
        cout << "Socket connect error: " << errno << '\n';
        close(clientSocket);
        return -1;
    }
    
    while (true) {

        cout << "Enter a message: ";

        string message;
        if (!getline(cin, message))
            break;

        if (!sendString(clientSocket, message))
            break;
        
        if (message == "Fin")
            break;
        
        if (!readString(clientSocket, message))
            break;
        
        cout << "Message from server: " << meessage << '\n';

        if (message == "Fin")
            break;
    }
    
    cout << "Client is shutting down...\n";
    close(clientSocket);
    
    return 0;
}


"Make sure to bind() your server socket to the local LAN IP that is directly connected to the router/Internet where the client will be coming from" - not sure what you meant by that but it's at best oddly worded, or more likely wrong.   That's not necessary at all.   It just has to be routable from the client by some mechanism.  Nothing has to be directly connected to a router/internet.

@xaxxon I re-worded it

@xaxxon Sir, i tried and i took a error message that named "connect error 60". In addition i used two different code. The first one is the new one above and second one is just including with my own code serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; this part of line. So my problem still persists.

@Mert Which platform are you running the code on? On some systems, error 60 is ENOSTR (Device not a stream). On others, it is ETIMEDOUT. Etc.  In any case, you can't connect() a socket to INADDR_ANY, only to a real IP.

It's not an inaddr_any problem for sure.   It never was.   You were binding fine (though inaddr_any is the best option to make sure it works).   Did you set up port forwarding on your router?   Your code was never the fundamental problem (though it does need fixing as the answer pointed out).   That's why it worked locally (at least it worked well enough) but doesn't work across the internet.    To re-emphasize, this is a network configuration problem -- not a code problem.  You can't fix this in your code.

@RemyLebeau Sir, i am using the silicon macOS version.

@xaxxon Sir i got it. i didn't handle it any set up port forwarding on my router. i am gonna care it.

@Mert "i am using the silicon macOS version" - in that case, error 60 is ETIMEDOUT

@RemyLebeau i guess i began to understand. First of all i am a new one in network world. i tried to connect with ip address of my friends but his ip address just in his local area so i should find his routers ip address because routers ip address uses in internet.(i am not sure but it sounds make sense). i am gonna read all of the messages and search again.

@Mert Yes, you would need to connect() to your friend's public router WAN IP (to get that, he can look inside his router's config, or simply visit a site like https://www.whatismyip.com). And he needs to configure his router to port-forward the WAN port to the LAN server port.

@RemyLebeau Thanks a lot sir. i have learnt many things thanks to you.
